# angular6 result from httppost subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm learning angular and i'm trying to do component which provides users registration to my web api.

in my component i have following code on form submit:

```
 onSubmit(contactFormRef: NgForm) {
    const result = this.usersService.CreateUser(this.registerDto);
    contactFormRef.reset();
  }
```

UsersService:

```
 CreateUser(dto: UserCreateDto): boolean {
    const endpoint = ApiQueryService.ApiEndpoint + this.postUserEndpoint;
    let result: any;

    let d = new Date(dto.birthDate.year, dto.birthDate.month - 1, dto.birthDate.day);
    dto.userDto.birthDate = d.toJSON();
    const password = dto.password;
    this.client.post(endpoint, dto.userDto).subscribe(x =>
    {
      result = x;
      const registerDto: RegisterDto = {Password: password, UserId: result};
      const registerResult = this.authService.RegisterUser(registerDto);
      return registerResult;
    });

    return false;
  }
```

and the AuthService:

```
 RegisterUser(dto: RegisterDto): boolean {
    let isSuccess: boolean = false;
    const endpoint = ApiQueryService.ApiEndpoint + this.registerEndpoint;
    this.client.post(endpoint, dto, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(response => {
      isSuccess = response.status === 200;
      return isSuccess;
    });
    return isSuccess;
  }
```

my problem is that i would like to return isSuccess from this:

```
this.client.post(endpoint, dto, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(response => {
      isSuccess = response.status === 200;
      return isSuccess;
    });
```

to the compomonent 
and in the component i will do something if result is not success,
but it always returning the result from code after subscribing, so the component always gets false result

[image: what i want to achieve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pipe map() in the AuthService, return what you need, handle it in the UserService, return some boolean again and subscribe in the component. So the services will return `Observable<boolean>`

AuthService:

```
RegisterUser(dto: RegisterDto): Observable<boolean> {
    const endpoint = ApiQueryService.ApiEndpoint + this.registerEndpoint;
    return this.client.post(endpoint, dto, {observe: 'response'})
    .pipe(
        map(response => response.status === 200),
    );
}
```

UserService:

```
CreateUser(dto: UserCreateDto): Observable<boolean> {
    const endpoint = ApiQueryService.ApiEndpoint + this.postUserEndpoint;
    let result: any;
    let d = new Date(dto.birthDate.year, dto.birthDate.month - 1, dto.birthDate.day);
    dto.userDto.birthDate = d.toJSON();
    const password = dto.password;
    return this.client.post(endpoint, dto.userDto).pipe(
        switchMap(result => {
            const registerDto: RegisterDto = {Password: password, UserId: result};
            return this.authService.RegisterUser(registerDto);
        }),
    );
}
```

Component:

```
onSubmit(contactFormRef: NgForm) {
    this.usersService.CreateUser(this.registerDto).pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(result => {
            // do what you need and then reset the form
            contactFormRef.reset();
        });
}
```

So it goes from the AuthService through the UserService and you subscribe only once at the end in the component.

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit and add some contextual code.

Answer (score 0):

Because post `this.client.post` method is asynchronous, and return isSuccess below that method is synchronous statement that executes first, so you can fix this by returning `this.client.post.subsribe(response => {... })`

```
 RegisterUser(dto: RegisterDto): boolean {
    let isSuccess: boolean = false;
    const endpoint = ApiQueryService.ApiEndpoint + this.registerEndpoint;
    return this.client.post(endpoint, dto, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(response => {
      isSuccess = response.status === 200;
      return isSuccess;
    });

  }
```